# What's the optimal mysql datatype field to store bcc mails

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have an script for sending bulk emails and I was wondering which is the best datatype to store those BCC emails on my DB.

Every time I send an email, I store this email on my database for future records. Currently I was using the method 1 row per email, but due to the bulk emails system I have now, I need just to store 1 record with many BCC emails

would it be ok to use just a VARCHAR field ?

PD : This field would usually storage about 50 emails.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

I currently save the email content, so I just want to know the data-type for this field as I'm not sure if VARCHAR 255 will be optimal enough.

Comment: If your system forces you to de-normalise your data, then something is wrong with it.

Comment: Do you want to store the mail content? Or subject+content? Or recipients? Or all of it? What about the time the mail was sent?

Comment: I've just edited the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

varchar(255)

standard in any enterprise web application

Answer (score 0):

I wont use that approach.

First, the max length of varchar is 255, so if you plan to store 50 mails addresses, it could be only 5 characters long, that wont be enough.

You could use TEXT, but that anyways, **storing more than one address in the same field is not a good approach**. you should use a row for every address, and use a sendId or something like that to have them related.

If you store other information for the mail, like the content, and etc, you can use a second table with just the emails, and the id of the row in the main table that contains all the rest of the information.

In this way you can better handle everything, you can count the number of recipient, filter, order, search, avoid duplicates, retrieve distinct emails to news sends, and manage records in a much more convenient way

Answer (score 0):

According to our edit, you only want to save the mail content. VARCHAR 255 is restricted to 255 characters, so if a mail exceeds this (I assume a lot of mails will exceed this), the characters after position 255 will be lost.
You better use TEXT which has a limit of 65.535 characters (see http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_data_types.php), so no text will be cut.

If you cau can foresee that your mails will also exceed the 65.535 characters limit (but that's a lot for mails), you might have a look at MEDIUMTEXT (16.777.215 characters) or even LONGTEXT (4.294.967.295 characters).

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can assign datatype as `varchar(32765)`. As per the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html), your column `should not be NULL`.

To store the email content, choose `mediumtext` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Unicode supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization) email.